# How to Change the Schema name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I´m developing an ASP.NET MVC app that uses EF 4.1 Code First.

I have to change the default schema name (dbo) to another name.

I tried this:

```
public string SchemaName;

public void MyContext()
{
    SchemaName = GetSchemaName();
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().ToTable("TB_ACC_HOLDERS", SchemaName);
}
```

But it´s not working. When I get a new instance of my Context and call some of my Tables.. the generated query still with "dbo" schema name.

Anyone have some idea to solve that?

Comment: You'll need to make that configuration change for every entity in the context - it isn't a global setting. Otherwise, you're doing it right.

Comment: I do that, but it doesn´t work :-(

Comment: Do you have `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` in your overridden `OnModelCreating`?

Comment: I was able to do this fine. I put a schema of SYSTEM on and it worked. Did you originally generate the database with dbo and switch it afterwards? Maybe it can't detect the schema changing as a reason to drop your database.

Comment: After a hard debug.. I found the error. My variable was being started in the constructor of the DataContext when running OnModelCreating arrived at the property was null. :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some hours in debug mode, I get the error.

At the constructor, I get the schema name on connectionString and set the property (schemaName) whit the value.

But, when the execution get the OnModelCreating() method, my schemaName property was set, who knows why, to NULL.

Then I put the schemaName variable fixed on code at the method. When I do that everything are right.

Thanks everybody!

Here, the code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //It works fine
    var schemaName = "SYSTEM";
    modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().ToTable("TB_ACC_HOLDERS", schemaName);
}
```

Comment: I am using this code to connect to Oracle Database without use DevArt connector. It´s hard, but it isn´t impossible! I´ll post the all code later! :)