# How to change the schema via connection string when connecting to Oracle using Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework-4, schema, connection-string

When I generated the EDMX file it set the Schema for each EntitySet

```
<EntitySet 
    Name="TableName"
    EntityType="Model.Store.TableName"
    store:Type="Tables"
    Schema="MySchema" />
```

The problem is that if I want to switch to the production database I have to change the EDMX since I don't know how to choose the Schema in the connection string.

How to do it?

Comment: Is the code first approach an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code first method is an option you can override the OnModelCreating method in your DbContext class.  In the OnModelCreating method you can put logic in to detect oracle and rename the schema accordingly.  The code first approach has been asked about [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215400/how-to-change-the-schema-name)

Answer (score 10):

I just had to edit the EDMX and remove the Schema from every EntitySet

```
<EntitySet 
    Name="TableName"
    EntityType="Model.Store.TableName"
    store:Type="Tables" />
```

Now it connects to the default schema for a given user.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. We had the same problem at my company and we couldn't figure it out. We already wasted hours on it and were working on plan B (use SQL server instead of Oracle), but your answer saved the day!

Comment: Awesome I didn't know how to change it because I'm working in a project with database first

Comment: Thanks a lot you save me a lot of time.